# Using Express with ReactRouter

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I'm using create-react-app to make a site, and I have created an express backend by setting up the react app to proxy to the express server, as per [this guide](http://ericsowell.com/blog/2017/5/16/create-react-app-and-express).

I want my app to have multiple pages - I read somewhere that this can only be done with React Router - is this true - do I need React Router to implement this or is just using Express okay?

I guess the root of my question would be what is the difference between client-side routing with ReactRouter and server-side routing with Express?

What would be some generalized instances where I would need to use ReactRouter with Express together?

How would I use these two in tandem?

Comment: Express in React sites can be used to service a backend API such as doing the CRUD operations for a blog's database. Express would sit on the backend while react-router would handle any routes between the actual views/pages of the client-side app's components. Without react-router, your client-side app would have to go back out to the server and request more resources(which affects performance). With react router, your site is requested once from the server, and then all subsequent renders of any pages are handled by react-router.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you so much!